# SSAS creating hierarchy for measure

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I have a requirement to display the measures of a cube in hierarchy (browsing in excel or SSRS).  Say I have four measures in fact table revenue `A`, revenue `B`, expense `A`.  I need to show it as

```
'+ Profit (calculated measure)

'--+Revenue (calculated measure)

'----+Revenue A (Fact measure)

'----+Revenue B (Fact measure)

'--+expense (calculated measure)

'----+Expense A (Fact measure)

'----+Expense B (Fact measure)
```

I created the calculated measure however I am unable to solve the hierarchy issue for the measures. I am not able to use Display folders or degenerate dimensions to achieve the result.  Can anyone help?

Comment: `[Measures]` is a single level hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a hierarchy if the purpose is just to be able to browse it. Create a named set in your cube(if changing cube structure is an option), or a query scoped named set(if it should be temporarily created) and put all the requisite measures into it.

```
WITH SET MySetOfMeasures AS
{
    Measures.Profit,

    Measures.Revenue,

    Measures.[Revenue A],

    Measures.[Revenue B],

    Measures.expense,

    Measures.[Expense A],

    Measures.[Expense B]
}
```

Then you can invoke this set in your MDX.

```
SELECT MySetOfMeasures ON 0 FROM [YourCube]
```